# What is an Unbeecoming Word™?

Tags: pattern, english, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Unbeecoming Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

[image: Examples of Unbeecoming Words™]

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Unbeecoming Words™,Not Unbeecoming Words™
FASHION,STYLE
FORMULA,RECIPE
FUNKY,WEIRD
INFORM,EDUCATE
INFORMAL,CASUAL
JOURNALISM,REPORTING
LIQUOR,BEER
MASONRY,BRICKWORK
SAILOR,MIDSHIPMAN
SQUAWK,SQUEAL
SQUIRM,WIGGLE
UNFAIR,CRUEL
UNIFORMS,OUTFITS
URINAL,TOILET
```

Comment: Should the right hand column be labelled "beecoming words"? :)

Comment: @IanF1 I *did* think about that but I already had the [Beecumming](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/23958/9000) puzzle in mind and didn't want to confuse them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Unbeecoming words

> don't include letters that are sounded with an `ee` when said: `BCDEGPTVZ` (bee, see, dee ...). Hence, unb**ee**coming.

Comment: I don't get it; you *stylee* your hair in the morning?

Comment: I like that there is no `Z` on either side of the list, to accommodate those who pronounce it either "zed" or "zee".

Comment: @user1717828 "T" is pronounced "tee", and "style" is spelled with a "T", thus it is *not* "un**bee**coming"

Comment: Eye Ass-Tea-Why-Ale-Ee my hair in the morning!