# What is a Beecumming Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Beecumming Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Beecumming Words™ | Not Beecumming Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| CENTAUR | JACKALOPE |
| EDUCATING | INFORMING |
| GLACIER | ICEBERG |
| INTEGRALS | DERIVATIVES |
| MASTERING | PRACTICING |
| MIRACLES | WONDERS |
| MISCREANT | VAGABOND |
| SCREWING | HAMMERING |
| SECLUDED | HIDDEN |
| STRANGLED | CHOKED |
| TRIANGLE | HEXAGON |
| WETLANDS | SWAMP |
| WILDCAT | GRIZZLY |
| WRESTLING | FIGHTING |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Beecumming Words™,Not Beecumming Words™
CENTAUR,JACKALOPE
EDUCATING,INFORMING
GLACIER,ICEBERG
INTEGRALS,DERIVATIVES
MASTERING,PRACTICING
MIRACLES,WONDERS
MISCREANT,VAGABOND
SCREWING,HAMMERING
SECLUDED,HIDDEN
STRANGLED,CHOKED
TRIANGLE,HEXAGON
WETLANDS,SWAMP
WILDCAT,GRIZZLY
WRESTLING,FIGHTING
```

---

Things that are not relevant include:

- capitalization
- whether "y" is a consonant or a vowel
- any sort of mathematical computation (the connection is a single step)
- pronunciation (e.g. "WURSTGILEDMARST" abides by the rule)

Some more words that fail the rule include "BEECUMMING", "question_asker", and "Engineer Toast". The title's spelling is intentional and SFW.

Comment: That title seems dirty...

Comment: @Deusovi It does look that way, yes, but it is a coincidence. The spelling is intentional and SFW.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you take the

> Unique Letters from E. E. Cummings' full name (Edward Estlin Cummings)

then you get

> acdegilmnrstuw

Which are the letters found in @Dr Xorile's answer as common letters! This means that the definition of a Beecumming Word™ is that it

> is composed only of letters found in the name "Edward Estlin Cummings"

Comment: oh my god, I thought about this, but I was so hung up on figuring out the rule that I had the exclusivity backwards. good job!

Answer (score 5):

I don't have an answer, but here's some basic analysis that may help (and may hinder):

Common letters: acdegilmnrstuw
No letters that appear in beecumming words only
Letters that appear in unbeecumming words only: bfhjkopvxyz
Letters that appear in neither group: q

I spent a while looking at the poetry of EE Cummings, but I was left none the wiser (at least for this puzzle - I'm sure the poetry was good for me in other ways)

Comment: I think that `u` isn't as useful as it seems (sadly), in the question comments OP says "question_asker" is not becumming.

Comment: Good catch. I was kind of assuming that a subset of the unbeecumming words only was going to be the key

Comment: I try to use every letter but I just couldn't find one I liked with a `Q`. The fact that it is left out is of no significance.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a Beecumming word is

> Used in the works of E.E. Cummings. That seems like what the OP is implying with the name Beecumming Word, but I haven't had any luck finding the list of words in several collections of his works.  I'm not sure if I'm using incorrect or incomplete sources, but so far no word from either list has appeared in my searches.  However, the implication seems so strong that I'm willing to hazard this as a guess.

Comment: This is probably it, but you should add explanation - typically answers with no reasoning behind them are deleted.

Comment: You got the clue in the title correct. However, you're still a little off-target. `STARCRAFT` is Beecumming™ but `WARCRAFT` is not. [Dr Xorile](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/23965/9000) has some useful analysis.